# How do I check if opencv-python lib is installed while installing other opencv-python flavor via requierements.txt?

Tags: python, installation, pip

The problem is that sometimes I need to use `opencv-contrib-python` in rare cases and my lib depends on `opencv-python`. I want to have convenient installation for my lib depending on whether I need or don't need `opencv-contrib-python`.

I have added an if statement that checks whether any version of `opencv-python` is already installed in virtual environment. Mentioned if statement doesn't work when installing my library using pip or requirements.txt, but works when I directly installing it using `python setup.py install`.

How do I make it work for pip installation?

Here's an if statement from my setup.py:

```
# Check if opencv-python is already installed
try:
    importlib.import_module("cv2")
    opencv_installed = True
    print("Version of opencv-python is already installed")
except ImportError:
    opencv_installed = False

if not opencv_installed:
    INSTALL_REQUIRES.append("opencv-python>=4.5.5.62, <5.0.0.0")
```